# Use remote host as proxy to connect another client in powershell

Tags: powershell, proxy, remote-access

I have main server which added to a lot of remote machines as trusted host. I have access to this server by RDP. But I want to use my local machine to connect to remote machines. I can add my machine to trusted host into every user, but it's not good solution, because:

- I don't have a static IP
- it's not secure
- it's more difficult, than just use server as proxy

Can I use remote server machine as something like proxy in order to connect directly to endpoint host, without enter in server session?

Comment: Check this : http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/04/04/enabling-multihop-remoting.aspx - or maybe you can use a VPN ?

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you exactly want to achieve but you can also try use PowerShell web access.